# React typescript Object.assign return type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, destructuring

I have this small custom hook which returns an `Object.assign` result. In documentation it says that this returns an array, but the example below can be used with array destructuring AND object destructuring.

Code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useStateExtended = (initialValue, initialLoading = false) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState(initialValue);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(initialLoading);

  return Object.assign([data, setData, loading, setLoading], { data, setData, loading, setLoading })
};

export default useStateExtended;
```

This code can be used in the following ways:

```
const {data, setData, loading, setLoading} = useStateExtended({});
const [data, setData, loading, setLoading] = useStateExtended({});
```

How does this work? Why can I destructure both like it is an array and an object?

Secondly: How to type this in Typescript? Data types are:

```
data: any;
setData: (data: any) => void;
loading: boolean;
setLoading: (boolean) => void;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use square-bracket destructuring on anything with an iterator, including, most notably, arrays.

You can use curly-bracket destructuring on *any* object (and arrays are objects).

When you do

```
Object.assign([data, setData, loading, setLoading], { data, setData, loading, setLoading })
```

You create an array which has both normal array indicies `[0]`, `[1]`, but *also* has properties `.data`, `.setData`, etc. This is pretty weird in Javascript, but since arrays are objects, and since objects can have arbitrary key-value pairs assigned to them, it's legal.

So, you can retrieve properties from the object either by using `[` destructuring, invoking the array's iterator, *or* by using `{` destructuring, extracting the named properties from the object.

That said, this isn't something you *should* do, because (as your question demonstrates), it's *kind of confusing* what's going on, and readability is probably the most important factor for code. Arrays should pretty much never have arbitrary key-value pairs (except in the case of a regular expression match, in which case the additional properties are generated by the interpreter itself).

To type it, use generics for the type of `initialValue` so it can be passed to `useState`, and declare the array `as const` so that the array destructuring retrieves the right types in the right order:

```
const useStateExtended = <T extends unknown>(initialValue: T, initialLoading = false) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<T>(initialValue);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(initialLoading);
    return Object.assign([data, setData, loading, setLoading] as const, { data, setData, loading, setLoading })
};
```

Comment: Thanks! and How would I type this in typescript?

Comment: I added the types to the question. What would you recommend? I think it is really concenient that I can use both array AND object destructuring because I am using them both

Comment: Had to install a React playground to try it out. See edit for an example of how to type it. But there shouldn't be any need for having *both* array properties *and* object properties for the same data - choose one method (an array or an object) and then use it everywhere, once one method works, there shouldn't be a need to use the other